# Serializing input type Time outputs strange string

Tags: jquery, asp.net, serialization

I am using ASP.NET MVC and JQuery and am trying to serialize a `TextBox` with an input type of `time`. Here's my code:

```
@Html.TextBox("ScheduleTime", null, new { @type = "time" })
```

And my JQuery code which grabs the `ScheduleTime` from the form and attempts to serialize it into my query string object:

```
time: $form.find('#ScheduleTime').val()
```

And I then convert the string to a query string using the `$.param` function.

When '02:31 PM' is entered into the textbox I receive this:

```
time=14%3A31
```

I don't understand where the `%3A` comes from nor do I understand it's relevance here. It's not a reference to whether the time is AM or PM because the time is formatted in military time. Any idea as to why it is serializing to such a strange format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of $.param is to [serialize content for use in a URL or ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/).  A colon is encoded to %3A for safe use in a URL.  You can see a list of other character encodings [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I didn't think about the encoding. Silly me.